# C error - undefined reference to pow in Eclipse IDE - can use it in 'main' function but not in others. I AM using "-lm" compiler flag

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

const short int Z = 2;

const int parts = 1000;
const double epsilon = 1e-5;

typedef double (*func_n_l_r)(int, double);

double R_nl(int n, int l, double r) {
    return 2 * pow(Z, 1.5) * exp(-r * Z );
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%f",pow(3,2));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In main it compiles and displays the results (if I comment out the R_nl function, of course), but it gives me an error in the R_nl function (same with the `exp` function).

Using Eclipse Juno for c/c++ developments.

[EDIT]: Using -lm flag.

[EDIT]: Using gcc compiler with arguments `-lm -E -P -v -dD "${plugin_state_location}/specs.c"` from Eclipse IDE - linux ubuntu 13.04.

[EDIT]: Compiler output, and i don't know why it doesn't see the `-lm` argument i gave it in the configurations.... :|

```
08:13:52 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Helium ****
Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "MinGW GCC" that is unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway.
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -o Helium src/Helium.o 
src/Helium.o: In function `R_nl':
/home/shefuto/Dropbox/pt_sqala/Master 2/sem2/nagy/Helium/Debug/../src/Helium.c:28: undefined reference to `pow'
```

[EDIT]: SOLVED : http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=68204/

Apparently there's a special options page for that, where you can specify linker arguments, where 'm' is the library you want to add, and it adds the option `-lm` automatically.

Comment: Your program doesn't even *call* `R_nl`.

Comment: @CarlNorum but it should not return error

Comment: How can it return an error if it's not even called?

Comment: @CarlNorum AFAIK, the fact that it calls the function or not shouldn't have anything to do with a compiler error. Besides my program has a lot of extra code where the function is actually code, i have just simplified it like this to get the essence.

Comment: What compiler error do you get?  What you've posted is 100% syntactically correct code.

Comment: 1. That's a linker error, not a compiler error. 2. You're *not* using the `-lm` flag, the command line is right there.  3. Your command line flags don't make sense - `-E` will cause it not to generate an object file anyway. 4. It looks like you have some toolchain problems with your IDE.  What happens when you build from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add -lm flag to compile(linker) command string.

```
gcc -lm ./main.c
```

See man pow

```
   #include <math.h>

   double pow(double x, double y);
   float powf(float x, float y);
   long double powl(long double x, long double y);

   Link with -lm. //<- Look here
```

Comment: I eventually did, but in Eclipse it was a little  complicated.